# Parse character

Tags: r, parsing, character

I have a character. For example: "RSSI:-41,-40,-41". There is a fast and easy way of parsing this character? I mean getting the values -41 -40 and -41.

Comment: Try `library(stringr);as.numeric(str_extract_all(str1, '[0-9.-]+')[[1]])`

Answer (score 1):

Based on the example provided, this also works

```
 scan(text=sub('.*:', '', str1), sep=",", quiet=TRUE)
 #[1] -41 -40 -41
```

`stri_extract_all_regex` from `stringi` would be faster

```
 as.numeric(stri_extract_all_regex(str1, '[-0-9.]+')[[1]])
 #[1] -41 -40 -41
```

#### data

```
 str1 <- "RSSI:-41,-40,-41"
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(stringr)
> str_extract_all("RSSI:-41,-40,-41", "[-0-9]+")
[[1]]
[1] "-41" "-40" "-41"
```